# Horizontal alignment in vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
With result_ws.Range(Cells(lastrow_result_ws + 1, 2), Cells(lastrow_result_ws + 2, 2))
    .Merge
    .HorizontalAlignment = x1Left
    .VerticalAlignment = x1Center
    .WrapText = True
End With
```

In the above code, the horizontal alignment is giving errors, because the cell is already left aligned. How to not get the error?

Comment: So remove it?..

Comment: both `x1` should be `xl` lower case `L` not the number `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `xlLeft` (Lower L) not `x1Left`.
Correct that and problem will be solved.

You can press `CTRL + SPACE` (windows) to autocomplete if you don't know the syntax.